# Python - How to get an integer from a list

Tags: python, list, typeerror, multiplication

I have an unknown list of numbers (the numbers get entered later in the program) and I am trying to find the largest one in the list, then store it in a variable so that I can do multiplication with it later. When I use `max()` I get an error saying "**TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'**" My code to find the largest number in the list is:

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    input_list = [inputArray]
    numb1 = max(input_list)
    print(numb1)
```

My full code was

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
input_list = inputArray
numb1 = max(input_list)
print(numb1)
location = input_list.index(numb1)
if numb1 == input_list[-1]:
    test2 = input_list[location-1]
    small_list = [test2]
    numb3 = small_list[0]
    return numb1 * numb3
elif numb1 == input_list[0]:
    test1 = input_list[location+1]
    small_list = [test1]
    numb3 = small_list[0]
    return numb1 * numb3
else:
    test1 = input_list[location+1]
    test2 = input_list[location-1]
    greater_list = [test1, test2]
    numb2 = max(greater_list)
    return numb1 * numb2
```

Comment: Show the full traceback. Unclear what `inputArray` is. Show a full example usage of your problem

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The issue is that you are making a list within a list. You are passing the function a list, which you put inside brackets, thus creating a 2d list. Try this:

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    input_list = inputArray
    #or:
    #input_list = [inputArray]
    #numb1 = max(input_list[0])
    numb1 = max(input_list)
    print(numb1)
```

Comment: Just use `max(inputArray)` if you're going to do that

Comment: I agree. However, I am trying to match my solution as closely to the OP's as possible.

Comment: Aren't you quickly assuming that the parameter is a list already? The mentioned error isn't even thrown by the max function

Comment: Cricket_007: That error showed up when I tried multiplying a number times the variable numb1.

Comment: Could you post your full code, including the multiplication?